# How to rewrite the digamma function to nonrecursive

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I ran a java program and got a `stackoverflow error` and this error was caused in a [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), the code is

```
public static double digamma(double x) {
    if (x >= 0 && x < GAMMA_MINX) {
        x = GAMMA_MINX;
    }
    if (x < DIGAMMA_MINNEGX) {
        return digamma(DIGAMMA_MINNEGX + GAMMA_MINX);
    }
    if (x > 0 && x <= S_LIMIT) {
        return -GAMMA - 1 / x;
    }

    if (x >= C_LIMIT) {
        double inv = 1 / (x * x);
        return Math.log(x) - 0.5 / x - inv
                * ((1.0 / 12) + inv * (1.0 / 120 - inv / 252));
    }
    return digamma(x + 1) - 1 / x;
}
```

the constant is defined as followed(the `private static final` is omitted for space consideration)

```
double GAMMA = 0.577215664901532860606512090082;
double GAMMA_MINX = 1.e-12;
double DIGAMMA_MINNEGX = -1250;
double C_LIMIT = 49;
double S_LIMIT = 1e-5;
```

As the `stackoverflow error` is caused by the level of the recursion is too deep so as to exceed the stack size of the thread(right?)so I increased the `Xss` parameter to `20M`,but the error persists, so I think I have to rewrite it to nonrecursive, but I have no experience to rewite a recursive function to nonrecursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but here it is:

```
public static double digamma(double x) {

    double value = 0;

    while (true){

        if (x >= 0 && x < GAMMA_MINX) {
            x = GAMMA_MINX;
        }
        if (x < DIGAMMA_MINNEGX) {
            x = DIGAMMA_MINNEGX + GAMMA_MINX;
            continue;
        }
        if (x > 0 && x <= S_LIMIT) {
            return value + -GAMMA - 1 / x;
        }

        if (x >= C_LIMIT) {
            double inv = 1 / (x * x);
            return value + Math.log(x) - 0.5 / x - inv
                    * ((1.0 / 12) + inv * (1.0 / 120 - inv / 252));
        }

        value -= 1 / x;
        x = x + 1;
    }

}
```

Since the code is almost tail-recursive, the trick is to throw a loop over the whole body.

The catch is the `- 1 / x` you have at the end. But since it's additive, you can just subtract `1 / x` from the result prior to starting the next iteration.

Comment: Wouldn't you want the `return` outside of the loop and some sort of `break` statement in the body?

Comment: That's just a matter of style. It doesn't really matter otherwise. (Unless Java complains about missing return statment.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I see there is still a recursive function call  at `digamma(DIGAMMA_MINNEGX + GAMMA_MINX)`, so this is not a pure nonrecursive version, so is there some way to rewrite it to a pure nonrecursive version?

Comment: I overlooked that call in the middle. I'll see if I can get rid of that one as well.

Comment: Actually, `digamma(DIGAMMA_MINNEGX + GAMMA_MINX)` is just a constant. Can't you just pre-compute it and replace it completely?

Comment: yes, you're right, I test your code with a double array`double[] x = { 55., 1.e-2,1.e-7, 1.e-13, 34., -1380.};`and two versions of the function give the same result except for `1.e-2` and the difference is just very small, for recursive version, the result for `1.e-2`is `-100.56088546075685` and nonrecursive version `-100.56088546075681`,I guess this difference can be ignored as they're almost equal. But I still want to know where the difference come from. Many thanks.

Comment: That tiny difference is just round off error. The iterative version changes the order in which the `-1/x` are summed up. The result is still correct, but slightly different since floating-point arithmetic isn't associative.

Answer (score 1):

scala version, from https://github.com/sameersingh/scala-utils/blob/master/misc/src/main/scala/org/sameersingh/utils/misc/Math.scala#L109

```
def digamma(xx: Double) = {
    var x = xx;
    var r = 0.0;

    while (x<=5) {
      r -= 1/x;
      x += 1;
    }

    var f = 1./(x * x);
    var t = f*(-1/12.0 +
            f*(1/120.0 +
            f*(-1/252.0 +
            f*(1/240.0 +
            f*(-1/132.0 +
            f*(691/32760.0 +
            f*(-1/12.0 +
            f*3617.0/8160.0)))))));
    r + log(x) - 0.5/x + t;
  }
```

Java version may be:

```
public static double digamma(double xx) {
    double x = xx;
    double r = 0.0;

    while (x<=5) {
      r -= 1/x;
      x += 1;
    }

    double f = 1./(x * x);
    double t = f*(-1/12.0 +
            f*(1/120.0 +
            f*(-1/252.0 +
            f*(1/240.0 +
            f*(-1/132.0 +
            f*(691/32760.0 +
            f*(-1/12.0 +
            f*3617.0/8160.0)))))));
    return r + log(x) - 0.5/x + t;
  }
```

Comment: The question is tagged Java. Does this answer the question, which is about Java? (I'm _pretty_ sure the answer is no, right? To be fair, I don't know much about Scala, but I know it's not Java)